# Fairy Tail's Aquarius can still materialize?

Tags: fairy-tail

In the Alvarez empire arc, she is shown to have materialized in spirit form once again to help out Lucy. 
But we all know the key that belonged to Lucy is broken.

What does this mean? are there 2 keys? 
I'm happy she's back though

Comment: maybe aquarius came by his own will. Same as Loke was at the beginning, in the first season (i mean he was materialized without a key)

Comment: Isn't Loke is refuse to back to spirit world rather than came by his own will, but may be not, I can't remember though :p

Comment: I think it's will be explain on next chapter, and I think this is spoiler for people who watch anime. I don't watch anime, so I don't know about Fairy Tail's last episode.

Comment: @JTR the last anime epoisde I saw on Crunchy roll was the end of the Tartaros arc

Comment: @JoeW if so, it is count as spoiler?

Comment: But Loki's key was intact, Aquarius' was not.

Comment: @JTR To be fair anything from the most recent issue of a manga or episode of an anime is a spoiler for a little while after it is released until people have time to read/watch it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was revealed in the following issue

> The key to summon Aquarius has been reborn somewhere in the world and the gate was opened by the Celestial King so that Aquarius could deliver a message to Brandish and Lucy